# Unable to reduce the number of points

Tags: 3d-view, topology

Unable to reduce the number of points.

i create terrain in terresculptor 2

moved this terrain to blender

tried to reduce through the decimate command, for some reason this command does not reduce the number of points. The collapse and planar commands work, they save the grid at each vertex, but at the same time they destroy the grid at each plateau. Un-subscribe does not work at all, the number of points does not decrease.

**how to reduce the number of points on the grid, but at the same time the points of view themselves were quickly distributed on the grid ???**

my cart-model

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yIxTqQLlo1WIo38BbusyFY8ZqPymkDVp/view?usp=sharing

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: the Unsubdivide option (in the Decimate modifier) should work, you need to go in Object mode, increase the Iteration value to see the effect, and click on Apply if you are good. You could also go in Edit mode, select all and Ctrl E > Unsubdivide, and set the Iteration value in the Operator box (bottom left of your 3D view)

Comment: @moonboots you didn't read the question

Comment: The number of vertices doesn't decrease as long as you don't apply the modifier. Please share your file

Comment: @moonboots https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yIxTqQLlo1WIo38BbusyFY8ZqPymkDVp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it asks for an unthorization, please unlock or use another platform  ;)

Comment: what do you mean by "at the same time they destroy the grid at each plateau"? Maybe I understand why unsubdivide doesn't work, it may be because you have tris instead of quads. Also, what you could try is the Remesh > Quad tool in the Object Data panel > Remesh

Comment: Another possible idea is to use a shrink-wrap modifier with a plane and project it on to the terrain. It should work, and you could make the plane as low or high poly as you want before shrinkwrapping.